# Custom Json ResponseBody in Swagger Http error

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, jhipster

In a Jhipster SpringBoot project I use swagger 2.0 ,

I want to have a static Json in this Http Error : 400

Custom Json wanted:

> { "ErrorID": -1 , "CustomMessage": "ERROR" }

I tried this in my **file.yml**

```
/path101:
    post:
      operationId: ID_OP
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Object_OP'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/reponse_Object_OP'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
          examples:
            application/json:
              ErrorID: -1
              CustomMessage: ERROR
```

In I still have the Springboot Normal error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-22T13:26:40.789+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/api/xxx/v1/path101"
}
```

I tried also updating **api.yml** file but I still have the same error:

```
    # API-first development with OpenAPI
    # This file will be used at compile time to generate Spring-MVC endpoint stubs using openapi-generator
    openapi: '3.0.1'
    info:
      title: 'MyApp'
      version: 0.0.1
    servers:
      - url: http://localhost:8082/api
        description: Development server
      - url: https://localhost:8082/api
        description: Development server with TLS Profile
    paths: {}
    components:
      responses:
#    Problem:
#      description: error occurred - see status code and problem object for more information.
#      content:
#        'application/problem+json':
#          schema:
#            $ref: 'https://opensource.zalando.com/problem/schema.yaml#/Problem'
     '400':
        description: Bad Request
        examples:
          application/json:
             ErrorID: -1
             CustomMessage: ERROR

  securitySchemes:
    jwt:
      type: http
      description: JWT Authentication
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT security:
  - jwt: []
```

Comment: I suppose you are using the openapi-client sub generator and that your specification file is `src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml`, right? Could there be a conflict between your 400 definition and zalando/problem lib that JHipster uses for error reporting?

Comment: I added the updated api.yml and I still have the same standard error

Comment: @Gaël-Marziou  Is something wrong with my update in api.yml ?

Comment: As I said, I suspect a conflict between openapi generated code and Zalando problem and if it is the case you won't fix it by modifying yaml. You must run under debugger, maybe put a breakpoint in ExceptionTranslator to see where Zalando is intercepting an argument validation exception and whether if it explains the JSON output you see.